# Where is the following integral defined and continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

We have the following integral:

[image]

My try to see it's domain:

$$x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2y^2} = \pi/2\cdot x - (-\pi/2)\cdot x = \pi\cdot x$$

However, the solutions say that the integral is not continuous but is defined at $\mathbb{R}. $ However, I don't know how does that work, since $F(x) = \pi\cdot x$ and as we see, that is continuous for every $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of principal value,
$$
f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{x}{1+(xy)^2}dy = \lim_{k\to \infty}\left[\arctan(xy)\right]_{-k}^k = \textrm{sgn}(x) \pi
$$

The sign of $x$ determines the sign of the integral, so you see it is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: Why can't I move the $x$ out of the numerator and then integrate?

Comment: You can do that, but why would you? The $x$ in the numerator is convenient for the antiderivative. In your calculations it seems that you have ignored the $x$ in the denominator...

Comment: But the derivative of $\arctan(xy)$ is $\frac{1}{1+(xy)^2}$ without the $x$ in the numerator

Comment: Sorry, I see there is also an inner function, my bad....